# Native Base Deck Swiper in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I just want to ask how to handle or is there a method that will handle when deck swiper of native base gets back to the first card. Lets say I have 100 cards but I display or render 25 cards, what I want to happen is when the number 25 card(which is the last) swipe, it will load the next 25 cards it will not go back to the first card.

Comment: not able to get your issue please add some more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Deck Swiper](http://nativebase.io/documentation) of [NativeBase](http://nativebase.io/) is just an UI component.

And what you have been asking for is something like paginating the data, which has nothing to do with NativeBase

Comment: thanks for the info, maybe I'll look for pagination package or create one